# For imbedding, the inclusion map need to be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|.\|_{X})$ and $(Y,\|.\|_{Y})$ be normed linear spaces such that $Y$ is a subspace of $X$. Then is the inclusion map $I: Y\to X$ always a continuous linear map?

Comment: Please specify: which norm will $X$ and $Y$ have? When $Y$ has the subspace norm it inherits from $X$, the inclusion map *will* be a continuous map with respect to the topology induced by the norms.

Answer (score 2):

In general it need not be true, but it is true in the particular case that $Y$ has the subspace norm it inherits from $X$.

Let me elaborate. To disprove the claim it is enough to find a vector space $X$ that can be endowed with two non-equivalent norms $||●||_1, ||●||_2$, because then one of the inclusion maps will not be continuous. One exmple of this is $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ with the norms $||●||_{\infty}$ the usual norm for the space and $||●||_{1}$ the $L^{1}$ norm. Note that the map $I:(L^{\infty}[0,1],||●||_{1}) \to (L^{\infty}[0,1],||●||_{\infty})$ is not continuous: for example $f_n(x)=x^{n}$ converge almost-everywhere to $f(x)=0$ and then by dominated convergence $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$ but the convergence is *not* achieved with respect to the $L^\infty$ norm, as $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|(x)^n-0|=x^n\geq (1-\delta)^n$ for all $x\in (1-\delta, 1]$ (which is a set of positive measure $\delta>0$) and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so $||f_n - f||_{\infty}\geq (1-\delta)^n$ for all $\delta \in (0,1)$ and then $||f_n - f||_{\infty}=1$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Another example of this is the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}$ with the $p$-adic norm and $\mathbb{Q}$ with the euclidean (absolute value) norm, which shows this can even occur in finite-dimensional vector spaces.

When $Y$ has the subspace norm inherited from $X$, a straightforward calculation gives us the result, as $$||y||_Y = ||y||_X$$ for all $y\in Y$.